# SSAS cube deployment to multiple machines

Tags: sql-server, ssas

We have SQL server database setup on each client production machine. Now i want to deploy the cube created to all client's production machine. How this can be achieved without creating different cubes for each client? Is it possible to just change the connection string and deploy it on the client machine. All client machine has same database schema but database name is different.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the fact that you have a SQL Server database set up on each client machine instead of a dedicated AS server that they all connect to (huge waste of money for licenses since you can't do AS on Express), in the AS Solution, go to Project on the menu bar and select Properties.  You should see a dialog box with 3 options on the left: Build, Debugging, Deployment.  Go to the Deployment tab. In there, you can select the Target Server (their computer name) and the database (their database name) that the cube will be deployed to.

Again, this is horrible practice and I assume there is some reason why you are deploying like this.  I imagine there will be permission issues you have to sort out for this type of deployment.

Comment: as of now, we have SQL server installed on each production machine. One dedicated machine for each client. Most of the client have same reports with some customized changes on each. All reports are deployed on report server (SSRS) on each clients dedicated SQL server. Now we are considering the SSAS, what should be the best way to implement it using SSAS + SSRS?

Comment: Why is this horrible? If I were a business providing reports to Coke and Pepsi it might make sense to physically segregate their data and allow Coke and Pepsi users access

Comment: @GregGalloway you can do this using cube security, no reason to have double the servers/licenses just for the sake of physical segregation.  Each partition of the measure group could be in their respective data file location.

Comment: @user2356907 Normally, you would have a single SSAS instance and a single SSRS instance, each using dedicated service accounts.  You can create SSRS reports based off a cube or just use plain Excel to do ad-hoc analysis.  If you are deploying out a cube to each individual machine, you lose that centralized data aspect and what one person creates might not look exactly the same as someone else.  Plus they can't share their reports since each user would have to change the connection string everytime.  Since you mentioned the cube is the same, a centralized approach would be more beneficial.

Comment: @TTeeple: it will hit the performance. Each client have millions of records.

Comment: @user2356907 millions of records is pretty normal for a cube.  Data warehouses tend to have 10+ million records in a single fact table.  As long as the cube is structured properly, partitioning is done correctly, and aggregations are set for the most common queries (you mentioned most of the reports are the same except for small changes), you should be able to query the cube with relative ease.